# sn-jnl asterix not coming for corresponding author

Tags: document-classes

I am writing a paper with `sn-jnl`. All authors are from single institute. So, I don't need to number the authors and affil. I proceed with:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{xcolor,bm,hyperref,mathtools,nicefrac, amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,
    amsthm, mathrsfs, textcomp, manyfoot, booktabs, algorithm, algorithmicx, algpseudocode, listings, natbib}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%

\begin{document}
\title[Hello]{Title}
\author*{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\affil{My Inst}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

This removes the asterisk from the corresponding author as well.

The asterisk only comes with the numbered affil, eg:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{xcolor,bm,hyperref,mathtools,nicefrac, amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,
    amsthm, mathrsfs, textcomp, manyfoot, booktabs, algorithm, algorithmicx, algpseudocode, listings, natbib}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%

\begin{document}
\title[Hello]{Title}
\author*[1]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author[1]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\affil[1]{My Inst}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to keep the asterisk against the corresponding author, but remove the affiliation number?